# Выдает такую ошибку....что делать?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

```
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at laravelproject.com Port 80
```

На данный момент:
права у папки `drwxrwxrwx`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName     test.laravel.com
ServerAdmin    webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot   var/www/projects/test.laravel.com
```

Прописано в хостах: `127.0.0.1` `test.laravel.com`

В файле apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/projects>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: `Require all granted`?

Comment: ...и ещё selinux проверить настройки. А вообще, вы б конфиги свои выложили, а то устроили тут соревнование телепатов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у меня было   DocumentRoot   var/www/projects/test.laravel.com
а нужно было добавить еще '/' вначале адресса!!!!
т.е. DocumentRoot   /var/www/projects/test.laravel.com
 а я чуть голову не сломал....пока не вычитал про разницу между абсолютным и относительным путем!
Вот кратко, если кому интересно!
 абсолютный путь идет из корня файловой системы, (то есть от знака /), а относительный-из той директории,в которой находишься.

Answer (score 2):

У нас решили так — в `Apache-2.4_server.conf` дописали:

```
<Directory /home/path_to/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

и выставили права доступа 755/644.

Comment: да, это мой сайт, переехал на новый комп, ставлю софт, апач, пхп проверил все норм стало, ставлю ларавель....и вот такая вот байда...

Comment: это виртуальный? а какое имя у папки, в которой лежит сайт?

Comment: В консоли при вводе этой команды :sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/laravelproject.com.conf

        В конфигах написано так:
        ServerName laravelproject.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /phpstorm/projects/laravelproject.com/public/