# помогите настроить auth в laravel 5.3!

Tags: php, laravel, auth

Здравствуйте, делаю shopping-cart по урокам  youtube-пользователя Mindspace (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufIK3PzwYf4&index=6&list=PL55RiY5tL51qUXDyBqx0mKVOhLNFwwxvH), на 12 мин 50 сек  , как в видео, 
перехожу на адресс_моего_сайта/signup и оно выдает:

```
404 (Not found)... The requested URL /signup was not found on this server.
```

UserController.php:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

public function getSignup() {

    return view('user.signup');
}

public function postSignup(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' =>  'email|required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
    ]);

    $user = new User([
        'email' =>$request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
    ]);
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('property.index');
}
```

}

web.php:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'PropertyController@getIndex',
    'as'  => 'property.index'
]);

Route::get('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getSignup',
    'as' => 'user.signup'
]);

Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignup',
    'as' => 'user.signup'
]);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на Github:

```
https://github.com/AlexBukreyev/auth
```

Добавил ссылку на гитхаб с этим проектом

Логи апача:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2017:12:53:57 +0200] "GET /signup HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/51.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2017:12:54:06 +0200] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php  HTTP/1.1" 200 2392 "http://localhost/phpmyadmin /index.php?target=server_databases.php&token=babaae057266e9780f747e4ff6486617"  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
```

file public /.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: А чем вам не подходит стандартная ? зачем свой велосипед делать ?

Comment: И ты проверили, у тебя другие запросы работают ? может у тебя переадресация не пашет ?

Comment: напиши в консоле `php artisan route:list`, посмотри что выдает

Comment: написал,вот скрин.
Запросы работают, роуты работают, бд работает, миграции работают,а вот приписка /signup - не хочет...

Comment: Может у тебя все же сервер не туда смотрит :) так то все вроде ок

Comment: Хорошо, а КАК проверить туда ли он смотрит?

Comment: просто я не пойму что не так.....ни админка, ни авторизация у меня норм не ставится почему-то....(((Начал уже по видеоурокам этого чувака делать, он вроде толлково все делает и объясняет,но что-то вот и у него на видосе запнулся на том же месте....(((

Comment: А как ты сервер запускаешь ? fpm или valet ? он же сейчас по моему уже есть под Ubuntu

Comment: Почитай статью , поставь [valet](https://laravel-news.com/valet-for-ubuntu-linux), в [доках](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet) как пользоваться найдешь!

Comment: вообще-то у меня apache 2.4 стоит....или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: запусти fpm и проверь, php artisan serv

Comment: Valet — среда для разработки в Laravel для минималистов, работающих на Mac. Без Vagrant, без Apache...Апач у меня стоит, долго мудохался, чтоб его настроить в свое время, но этот этап в прошлом.Если у меня есть апач-мне валет нужен?

Comment: php artisan serv    -   
Laravel development server started on http://127.0.0.1:8000/   все в порядке....

Comment: Добавил ссылку на гитхаб с этим проектом

Comment: Я думал у тебя уже давно все пашет, посмотри может у тебя апач не на ту папку показывает ! должно на public

Comment: все верно, смотрит на папку public......((если бы работало-я бы отметил ответ или написал бы сам к чему пришел....у меня получается НЕ срабатывает переход по адрессу /signup...
толкьо начал изучение ларавель, поэтому и на гитхаб выложил проект,чтоб знатоки и гуру ларавель могли глянуть и сказать где и что я не учел...чтоб и я из трейни в гуру ларавель превратился тоже))

Comment: Ну если у тебя fpm работает, значит проблема у тебя с настройками apach

Comment: Orange,  а что с настройками может быть не так???куда копать всмысле?

Comment: Я даже тебе сказать точно не могу, возможно у тебя проблема с mod_rewrite, возможно у тебя apache ругается на строку Options -MultiViews, которы лежит в public/.htaccess, без логов сервера, сложно сказать

Comment: вот добавил строки из логов сервера и файл .htaccess

Comment: Это вот ни о чем не сказала, говорит только что страница не найдена, ты уверен что правильно путь проставлен покажи свой настройки VirtualHost ? и скажи все же почему не хочешь поставить valet на ubuntu ?

Comment: Orange,  я с настройками апача мучался пару недель назад вот ссылка на мой вопрос и решение, чтоб сюда не дописывать еще,а то и так много инфы   :      http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624095/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: Valet — среда для разработки в Laravel для минималистов, работающих на Mac. Без Vagrant, без Apache...Апач у меня стоит, долго мудохался, чтоб его настроить в свое время, но этот этап в прошлом.Если у меня есть апач-мне валет нужен?

Comment: судя по твоему ответу там, ты public так директорию и не дописал, как тебе посоветовали в ответе выше ! А ты у нас я смотрю глобалист, запомни иди от простого к общему, а не на оборот!!!

Comment: Valet поддерживает только Mac - это предложение из официаль ных доков, так что валет отпадает

Comment: Я тебе ссылку кинул!!!!! на Ubuntu установщик!!! https://laravel-news.com/valet-for-ubuntu-linux

Comment: ооо!спасибо!надеюсь, что валет решит данную проблему)

Comment: Я  тебе ссылку кинул еще 5-м сообщением

Comment: Мне в том ответе посоветовали public директорию прописать, а  я прописал для ВСЕХ проектов на всю папку!

Comment: Ты ведь пронимаешь, что для каждого проекта  стартовая директория должна быть своя ? Это html файлы у тебя будут для всех работать, ну и php скрипты, но никак не framework

Comment: понимаю, спасибо огромное ща буду пробовать!

Comment: прописал условия в конфигах апача для <Directory /var/www/projects/auth.laravel.com/public> .....НЕ решило...все равно 404....ща буду валет тогда пробовать....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, дело было в настройках апача! Нужно включить rewrite через консоль:

```
 apache2ctl -M | grep -i rew
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```